# smtpmail-smtp-service defaults to 25 in Doom Emacs [Solved]

Tags: mu4e, doom, smtpmail

I'm having trouble setting up mu4e. My configuration in `config.el`:

```lisp
(require 'smtpmail)
(setq message-send-mail-function 'smtpmail-send-it
   starttls-use-gnutls t
   smtpmail-stream-type 'starttls
   smtpmail-starttls-credentials '(("smtp.gmail.com" 587 nil nil))
   smtpmail-auth-credentials (expand-file-name "~/.authinfo.gpg")
   smtpmail-smtp-user "[email protected]"
   smtpmail-default-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
   smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com"
   smtpmail-smtp-service 587)
```

My problem is that `smtpmail-smtp-service` defaults 25 after Doom Emacs initialization and I can´t figure out where this is being set.

I added the following line after the above code and restarted doom emacs:

```lisp
(add-variable-watcher 'smtpmail-smtp-service (lambda (s n o w) (debug)))
```

and this is what I get:

```
Debugger entered: nil
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/pablo/.doom.d/config.el" "/home/pablo/.doom.d/config.el" nil t)
  load("~/.doom.d/config" nil nomessage)
  (condition-case e (load path noerror 'nomessage) ((debug doom-error) (signal (car e) (cdr e))) ((debug error) (setq path (locate-file path load-path (get-load-suffixes))) (signal (cond ((not (and path (featurep ...))) 'error) ((file-in-directory-p path (expand-file-name "cli" doom-core-dir)) 'doom-cli-error) ((file-in-directory-p path doom-core-dir) 'doom-core-error) ((file-in-directory-p path doom-user-dir) 'doom-user-error) ((file-in-directory-p path doom-profile-dir) 'doom-profile-error) ((file-in-directory-p path doom-modules-dir) 'doom-module-error) ('doom-error)) (list path e))))
  doom-load("~/.doom.d/config")
  byte-code("\305\306!\204\f\0\305\307!\203\351\1\10\30\310\311!\211\203\"\0\211@\312\1!\210\1A\266\202\202\21\0\210\313\21\314\22\315\316\317\"\210\315\320\321\"\210\315..." [doom-context doom-modules doom-disabled-packages custom-file doom-module-context doom-context-p init reload ensure-list modules doom-context-push #<hash-table equal 38/65 0x158a7ac628f3> nil setplist :core (nil [0 -110 -110 :core nil nil nil]) :user (nil [1 105 -105 :user nil nil nil]) :completion (company [3 0 0 :completion company nil nil] ivy [4 0 0 :completion ivy nil nil]) :ui (doom [5 0 0 :ui doom nil nil] doom-dashboard [6 0 0 :ui doom-dashboard nil nil] doom-quit [7 0 0 :ui doom-quit nil nil] hl-todo [8 0 0 :ui hl-todo nil nil] modeline [9 0 0 :ui modeline nil nil] ophints [10 0 0 :ui ophints nil nil] popup [11 0 0 :ui popup (+defaults) nil] treemacs [12 0 0 :ui treemacs nil nil] vc-gutter [13 0 0 :ui vc-gutter nil nil] vi-tilde-fringe [14 0 0 :ui vi-tilde-fringe nil nil] workspaces [15 0 0 :ui workspaces nil nil]) :editor (file-templates [16 0 0 :editor file-templates nil nil] fold [17 0 0 :editor fold nil nil] snippets [18 0 0 :editor snippets nil nil]) :emacs (dired [19 0 0 :emacs dired nil nil] electric [20 0 0 :emacs electric nil nil] undo [21 0 0 :emacs undo nil nil] vc [22 0 0 :emacs vc nil nil]) :checkers (syntax [23 0 0 :checkers syntax nil nil]) :tools (ein [24 0 0 :tools ein nil nil] eval [25 0 0 :tools eval (+overlay) nil] lookup [26 0 0 :tools lookup nil nil] lsp [27 0 0 :tools lsp (+eglot) nil] magit [28 0 0 :tools magit nil nil] pdf [29 0 0 :tools pdf nil nil]) :lang (emacs-lisp [30 0 0 :lang emacs-lisp nil nil] latex [31 0 0 :lang latex (+pdflatex) nil] markdown [32 0 0 :lang markdown nil nil] org [33 0 0 :lang org (+pretty +pandoc +present) nil] python [34 0 0 :lang python (+eglot) nil] sh [35 0 0 :lang sh nil nil]) :email (mu4e [36 0 0 :email mu4e (+gmail) nil]) :config (use-package [2 -111 -111 :config use-package nil nil] default [37 0 0 :config default (+bindings +smartparens) nil]) [2 -111 -111 :config use-package nil nil] doom-load "~/.emacs.d/modules/config/use-package/init" [0 -110 -110 :core nil nil nil] "~/.emacs.d/lisp/init" doom-run-hooks doom-before-modules-init-hook doom-after-modules-init-hook doom-before-modules-config-hook [3 0 0 :completion company nil nil] "~/.emacs.d/modules/completion/company/config" [4 0 0 :completion ivy nil nil] "~/.emacs.d/modules/completion/ivy/config" [5 0 0 :ui doom nil nil] ...] 4)
  load("/home/pablo/.emacs.d/.local/etc/@/init.29.elc" noerror nomessage nosuffix)
  (progn (load init-file-name 'noerror 'nomessage 'nosuffix))
  (if init-file-name (progn (load init-file-name 'noerror 'nomessage 'nosuffix)))
  (let ((init-file-name (file-name-concat doom-profile-dir (format "init.%d.elc" emacs-major-version)))) (setq user-init-file t) (if init-file-name (progn (load init-file-name 'noerror 'nomessage 'nosuffix))) (if (eq user-init-file t) (progn (signal 'doom-nosync-error (list init-file-name)))) (setq user-init-file (concat (string-remove-suffix ".elc" user-init-file) ".el")))
  (progn (let ((init-file-name (file-name-concat doom-profile-dir (format "init.%d.elc" emacs-major-version)))) (setq user-init-file t) (if init-file-name (progn (load init-file-name 'noerror 'nomessage 'nosuffix))) (if (eq user-init-file t) (progn (signal 'doom-nosync-error (list init-file-name)))) (setq user-init-file (concat (string-remove-suffix ".elc" user-init-file) ".el"))))
  (if init-file-user (progn (let ((init-file-name (file-name-concat doom-profile-dir (format "init.%d.elc" emacs-major-version)))) (setq user-init-file t) (if init-file-name (progn (load init-file-name 'noerror 'nomessage 'nosuffix))) (if (eq user-init-file t) (progn (signal 'doom-nosync-error (list init-file-name)))) (setq user-init-file (concat (string-remove-suffix ".elc" user-init-file) ".el")))))
  (condition-case error (if init-file-user (progn (let ((init-file-name (file-name-concat doom-profile-dir (format "init.%d.elc" emacs-major-version)))) (setq user-init-file t) (if init-file-name (progn (load init-file-name 'noerror 'nomessage 'nosuffix))) (if (eq user-init-file t) (progn (signal 'doom-nosync-error (list init-file-name)))) (setq user-init-file (concat (string-remove-suffix ".elc" user-init-file) ".el"))))) ((debug error) (display-warning 'initialization (format-message "An error occurred while loading `%s':\n\n%s%s%s\n\nTo ..." user-init-file (get (car error) 'error-message) (if (cdr error) ": " "") (mapconcat #'(lambda (s) (prin1-to-string s t)) (cdr error) ", ")) :warning) (setq init-file-had-error t)))
  (let ((debug-on-error debug-on-error-initial)) (condition-case error (if init-file-user (progn (let ((init-file-name (file-name-concat doom-profile-dir ...))) (setq user-init-file t) (if init-file-name (progn (load init-file-name ... ... ...))) (if (eq user-init-file t) (progn (signal ... ...))) (setq user-init-file (concat (string-remove-suffix ".elc" user-init-file) ".el"))))) ((debug error) (display-warning 'initialization (format-message "An error occurred while loading `%s':\n\n%s%s%s\n\nTo ..." user-init-file (get (car error) 'error-message) (if (cdr error) ": " "") (mapconcat #'(lambda ... ...) (cdr error) ", ")) :warning) (setq init-file-had-error t))) (or (eq debug-on-error debug-on-error-initial) (progn (setq debug-on-error-should-be-set t) (setq debug-on-error-from-init-file debug-on-error))))
  (let ((debug-on-error-from-init-file nil) (debug-on-error-should-be-set nil) (debug-on-error-initial (if (eq init-file-debug t) 'startup init-file-debug)) (inhibit-null-byte-detection t)) (let ((debug-on-error debug-on-error-initial)) (condition-case error (if init-file-user (progn (let ((init-file-name ...)) (setq user-init-file t) (if init-file-name (progn ...)) (if (eq user-init-file t) (progn ...)) (setq user-init-file (concat ... ".el"))))) ((debug error) (display-warning 'initialization (format-message "An error occurred while loading `%s':\n\n%s%s%s\n\nTo ..." user-init-file (get (car error) 'error-message) (if (cdr error) ": " "") (mapconcat #'... (cdr error) ", ")) :warning) (setq init-file-had-error t))) (or (eq debug-on-error debug-on-error-initial) (progn (setq debug-on-error-should-be-set t) (setq debug-on-error-from-init-file debug-on-error)))) (if debug-on-error-should-be-set (progn (setq debug-on-error debug-on-error-from-init-file))))
  startup--load-user-init-file@init-doom(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x16e6aa77779e5cd7>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c61addc0b8a75>) t)
  apply(startup--load-user-init-file@init-doom (#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x16e6aa77779e5cd7>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c61addc0b8a75>) t))
  startup--load-user-init-file(#f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x16e6aa77779e5cd7>) #f(compiled-function () #<bytecode -0x1f3c61addc0b8a75>) t)
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

**EDIT**
I found out that `smtpmail-smtp-service`is being set to 25 in `custom.el`:

```lisp
 '(smtpmail-smtp-server "smtp.gmail.com")
 '(smtpmail-smtp-service 25)
```

I guess those lines are being included by the line that enables the mu4e module in `init.el`:

```
       :email
       (mu4e +gmail)
```

How can I set the value of `smtpmail-smtp-service` without changing that in `custom.el`?

Comment: Which `custom.el`? If the value 25 is being set via `customize`, then change it via `customize`, not `setq`.

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you. I used the Emacs Customize Interface to set `smtpmail-smtp-service` to 587.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem using [Emacs Easy Customization Interface](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Easy-Customization.html) to set variable `smtpmail-smtp-service` to 587.